# How to check which browser is running my Web-App

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a web-app, suppose a client has accesses http://server:port/mycontext/test.jsp page and after some logics on test.jsp I've sent an email with a link containing security  code (http://server:port/mycontext/validate.jsp?code=091028jskjk1joi1209).
Once user clicks on the link in the mail, validate.jsp code validates some logic and set the results to cookies which are taken up by test.jsp and auto closes. test.jsp talks to cookies every 1 second and loads new data if any.

Query-1 - Can we achieve this on multi-browser?
Why Query-1, If user has opened the test.jsp on Chrome and upon clicking the link on mail it may take the user to default browser maybe IE,Edge,FF.

Above logic not working cross browser. Please help.

Comment: Setting up cookie value for some logic wont work if user uses different browser or in incognito mode.

Comment: post more details and code, we can't help without knowing what you tried

Comment: @user1 - what i tried - suppose we have IE11 as default browser. my test.jsp page is sending mail to user with a link(validate.jsp?code=9jkajskajsndi2989). when user clicks on link. It should update my test.jsp with some values. This operation I'm achieving with cookies successfully. but cross browser not working.

Comment: @user1531038 - any idea how to achieve the functionality. I dont want to query DB regularly for getting updated data. Instead, was trying to do it through cookies.

Comment: @Ars For cross browser support, you need some common place to store such info at client place. Since you don't have control over clients workstation, you need some info to be stored at server side. If you don't want to query db often, probably you can use session object on application server. This is just a high level suggestion, since I don't have in-depth idea of your entire solution.